# Calling SNS ansible script using shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, ansible, amazon-sns

I have created an sns publishing ansible play book and trying to run it but its not working and giving me the error.. I am sending the whole **arn for the topic**. Does the sns component not parse the colons

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'snsTopicName' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/opt/jenkins/data/workspace/working/cicd-pipeline/working-cicd-pipeline/lib/helper/sns-publish.yml': line 25, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Publish Jenkins Error to SNS topic for failures\n      ^ here\n"
}
```

The calling script is

```
       if [ "$1" = "QA" ]
then
    ansible-playbook -vvv -c local "sns-publishQA.yml" --extra-vars "environment:'$environment' snsTopicName:'$snsTopicName'"
else
    ansible-playbook -vvv -c local "sns-publish.yml" --extra-vars "environment:'$environment' snsTopicName:'$snsTopicName'"
    fi

      if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        exit 1
      fi  
      cd -  
      }
```

The playbook is

```
- name: Publish Jenkins Error to SNS topic {{snsTopicName}}
  sns:
      msg: "Error happened when running the pipeline"
      subject: "Jenkins Error"
      topic: "{{snsTopicName}}"
      aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
      region: "us-east-1"
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can anybody please advise.. this is a big pain to use the sns api for ansible..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue.. It seems that ansible has problems compiling colon : send as parameter. You have to send the parameter value between double quotes to make this work. For eg the arn will look "arn:dfd:dfdf...."